# Dynamically build pipeline chain

Tags: c#, ml.net

Using code taken from [this example](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/master/machine-learning/tutorials/TaxiFarePrediction/Program.cs).

This code work:

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns(outputColumnName: "Label", inputColumnName: "FareAmount")
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "VendorIdEncoded", inputColumnName: "VendorId"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "RateCodeEncoded", inputColumnName: "RateCode"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "PaymentTypeEncoded", inputColumnName: "PaymentType"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "VendorIdEncoded", "RateCodeEncoded", "PassengerCount", "TripTime", "TripDistance", "PaymentTypeEncoded"))
            .Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.FastTree());
```

But I would like to Append dynamically at runtime like so:

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns(outputColumnName: "Label", inputColumnName: "FareAmount");
pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "VendorIdEncoded", inputColumnName: "VendorId"));
pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "RateCodeEncoded", inputColumnName: "RateCode"));
pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "PaymentTypeEncoded", inputColumnName: "PaymentType"));
pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "VendorIdEncoded", "RateCodeEncoded", "PassengerCount", "TripTime", "TripDistance", "PaymentTypeEncoded"));
pipeline.Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.FastTree());
```

None of the commands after the first have an effect. How can I dynamically chain Appends?

When trying:

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns(outputColumnName: "Label", inputColumnName: "FareAmount");
pipeline = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "VendorIdEncoded", inputColumnName: "VendorId"));
pipeline = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "RateCodeEncoded", inputColumnName: "RateCode"));
pipeline = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "PaymentTypeEncoded", inputColumnName: "PaymentType"));
pipeline = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "VendorIdEncoded", "RateCodeEncoded", "PassengerCount", "TripTime", "TripDistance", "PaymentTypeEncoded"));
pipeline = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.FastTree());
```

I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.ML.Data.EstimatorChain' to 'Microsoft.ML.Transforms.ColumnCopyingEstimator'" errors
[image]

When trying

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns(outputColumnName: "Label", inputColumnName: "FareAmount");
var pipeline2 = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "VendorIdEncoded", inputColumnName: "VendorId"));
pipeline2 = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "RateCodeEncoded", inputColumnName: "RateCode"));
pipeline2 = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "PaymentTypeEncoded", inputColumnName: "PaymentType"));
var pipeline3 = pipeline2.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "VendorIdEncoded", "RateCodeEncoded", "PassengerCount", "TripTime", "TripDistance", "PaymentTypeEncoded"));
var pipeline4 = pipeline3.Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.FastTree());
var model = pipeline4.Fit(dataView);
```

But then on the last line I get an "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Could not find input column 'VendorIdEncoded'
Parameter name: inputSchema'" error

Comment: Probably, just guessing though, it's because you need to use `pipeline = pipeline.Append(...`

Comment: Hi @CamiloTerevinto, Please see the image I added to the question

Comment: So you need to find out the base type for those 2 calls... What if you use `ITransformer pipeline = ...`?

Comment: Hi @CamiloTerevinto, Can you please check out the extra things I tried (added to the question) and see if you can think of anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Camilo Terevinto explained in the comment section, you need to get the results into `pipeline`:

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns(outputColumnName: "Label", inputColumnName: "FareAmount");
var pipeline2 = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "VendorIdEncoded", inputColumnName: "VendorId"));
pipeline2 = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "RateCodeEncoded", inputColumnName: "RateCode"));
pipeline2 = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "PaymentTypeEncoded", inputColumnName: "PaymentType"));
pipeline2 = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "VendorIdEncoded", "RateCodeEncoded", "PassengerCount", "TripTime", "TripDistance", "PaymentTypeEncoded"));
pipeline2 = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.FastTree());
```

The final answer is

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns(outputColumnName: "Label", inputColumnName: "FareAmount");
var pipeline2 = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "VendorIdEncoded", inputColumnName: "VendorId"));
pipeline2 = pipeline2.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "RateCodeEncoded", inputColumnName: "RateCode"));
pipeline2 = pipeline2.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "PaymentTypeEncoded", inputColumnName: "PaymentType"));
var pipeline3 = pipeline2.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "VendorIdEncoded", "RateCodeEncoded", "PassengerCount", "TripTime", "TripDistance", "PaymentTypeEncoded"));
var pipeline4 = pipeline3.Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.FastTree());
var model = pipeline4.Fit(dataView);
```

Comment: Thanks but this code does not work. From the second line there is a red squiggly line on all the lines with the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.ML.Data.EstimatorChain<Microsoft.ML.Transforms.OneHotEncodingTransformer>' to 'Microsoft.ML.Transforms.ColumnCopyingEstimator'. I added an image to my question

Comment: It is indeed better. So only the last two lines now are showing `Cannot implicitly convert type...` I tried continuing your solution using pipeline3 and pipeline4 and the next line `var model = pipeline4.Fit(dataView);` but I got the error: `: 'Could not find input column 'VendorIdEncoded' Parameter name: inputSchema' `

Comment: @adinas strange, especially since the initial code worked for you.

Comment: Hi, @lajos-arpad I've added the last code I tried to the question in case you would like to have a quick look and see if anything obvious comes to you. Thanks

Comment: @adinas that's a line which was not present in the code you originally shared here. Was it there before? Was it working? How was it looking alike initially if so?

Comment: You are absolutely right. The link to the example code was wrong too.I now corrected it. You can find it at https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/master/machine-learning/tutorials/TaxiFarePrediction/Program.cs I didn't think that last line was important regarding the question since it was not where I was getting errors...

Comment: @adinas the last error in your edited question tells you that VendorIdEncoded is not found. I think you need to take a look at the input schema. The column might be missing there.

Comment: Lajos Arpad, to fix the issue I needed to update lines 3 and 4 to pipeline2 = pipeline2.Append. I edited your answer and accepted. Thanks for your help